# Where can i find all available contribution targets for the new azure devops extensions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

The new azure extension development [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/develop/extensions) points to a sample project in [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample) where you can see different extension examples targeting different areas of the of the azure DevOps portal. However I am not able to find any documentation regarding all available contribution targets. Where do I find that information.

For instance one of the samples in the repo shows how to add a new menu option to the repository picker. This is how the contribution snippet looks:

```
{
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "sample-repository-picker-action",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.menu-item",
            "targets": [ "ms.vss-code-web.command-bar-repository-picker-actions" ],
            "properties": {
                "text": "Sample repository picker action",
                "uri": "dist/RepositoryActions/RepositoryActions.html",
                "iconName" : "Add",
                "registeredObjectId": "sample-repository-action"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see they target `ms.vss-code-web.command-bar-repository-picker-actions` Where do i find documentation of all the different targets available?

What I have tried is inspecting the azure DevOps portal with chrome Devtools hoping to see the target string as an html attribute in any of the elements. That was just a wild guess. This seems like an important piece of information to be documented for extension creation, where are those?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave commend here :-)

Comment: I need this as well. How can you extend if you don't know the targets?

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide) extension from Microsoft.

> This extension is designed to help extension developers discover the various components of Visual Studio Team Services that can be targeted by contributions from third party extensions, as well as the context data that is available at each target.

In addition, you can find a long list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/vss-extension.json).

Comment: Unfortunately both linked pages have not seen updates for quite a while. And even then they where far from complete.
So the answer to the OPs question really is: There is no complete list. And there is no way to reverse engineer the required information.