# Azure DevOps Boards - create button to switch tab

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing application for Azure DevOps Boards and got stuck on how to create 'link' to the different tab on Work item page? Specifically I have a hub on details page and want to add link to the different tab with details. So I already have plugin which adds hub and tab and I want to add kind of `Show Details` button to switch from hub to the tab. But I can't find any way how it can be achieved. Looks like tabs do not have own urls which can be used. So it must be some js call.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can i find all available contribution targets for the new azure devops extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716740/where-can-i-find-all-available-contribution-targets-for-the-new-azure-devops-ext)

Comment: I already have hub and tab on DevOps Boards. I used `ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-page` and  `ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group` for it. I'm looking for a way how to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Boards - create button to switch tab

Yes, I agree with you. The tab should be the js call.

If we want to add a `Show Details` button to switch from hub to the tab, we need get the url for the tab, so that we could add it in the properties:

```
"contributions": [
   {  
       ...
      ],  
      "properties": {  
        ... 
          "uri": "URLHere"  
      }  
   }
]
```

However, if we switch between these existing tabs, we will find that the URL in the browser has not changed. So, those tab should not be the URL type. We could not get the URL for those URL.

Besides, if we check the source code of this webpage, we could also to know those tabs are not URL call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I investigated how it's done natively and it looks like they are using some jquery/core package to locate the tab group and set active tab. But it looks like it can't be done from iframe.

Comment: @Andrew, Sorry for any inconvenience. Indeed, it seems that it cannot be achieved yet.